# SensorEventListener not working at all, none of the sensors have worked

Tags: events, listener, sensors, temperature

I'm trying to implement a temperature sensor on a virtual Pixel 4a, Ambient Temp sensor is included according to list of sensors.

When I run the program, the textView continues to print "Hello world!" instead of what setText in the onSensorChanged method provides.

Here is my code, any help will be amazing:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private TextView textView;
private Sensor tempSensor;
private Boolean tempSensorAvailable;
private int activityCode = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestActivityPermission();
    }

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) != null) {
        tempSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
        tempSensorAvailable = true;
    } else {
        textView.setText("Temperature Sensor is not available.");
        tempSensorAvailable = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    textView.setText(sensorEvent.values[0] + " Celsius");
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (tempSensorAvailable) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, tempSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (tempSensorAvailable) {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}

public void requestActivityPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.
            ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permission needed")
                .setMessage("Permission is needed to run this app.")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION},
                                activityCode);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION},
                activityCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mus call SensroManager.registerListener():

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int)